# Json для собственного класса

Tags: java, json, libgdx

Работаю в libGDX с сериализацией собственных классов.

Вопрос следующий: при десереализации `Json` в объект типа `Cooldown.class` (собственный класс) возникает ошибка

```
Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation
```

Дело в том, что в моем классе `Cooldown` есть переменная типа `Animation`. Ошибка требует создания пустого конструктора класса `Animation`. При этом, я не предполагаю, как мне можно его сделать в `Animation` (файл Read-Only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Твой класс Cooldown наследует интерфейс **Serializable**?

В этом интерфейсе есть два метода для чтения обьекта из JSONa и для записи. Если обьект имплементирует этот интерфейс, то класс Json будет использовать их для сериализации.

В противном случае будет использоваться Reflection и libGdx попытаеться сериализовать все поля обьекта, в том числе и Animation. Чтобы это предотвратить, инициализируй анимацию в пустом конструкторе, и поставь перед ее полем ключевое слово **transient**(говорит сериализатору о том что это поле не нужно сериализировать).

```
private transient Animation anim;

private Cooldown() {
    anim = new Animation(...);
}
```

Либо опять таки имплементируй Serialiable в Cooldown-е , и пропиши свой алгоритм сериализации (как по мне то это проще).

```
@Override
public void write(Json json) {
    //Сохраняешь то что нужно
}
```